# Intermittent Azure database connectivity from TFS build agents

Tags: sql-server, azure, tfs, azure-sql-database, azure-devops

I have the following setup:

1. Azure MSSQL database
2. TFS build server

Build server in one of its steps contacts Azure database and every so often I get an error message like below:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

The rate of these failures varies. Sometimes it's one failed build for ten successful ones. Sometimes, I get five failed builds in a row.

The error occurs irrespectively of whether the build server is connected to `mymssqlserver.database.windows.net` or `mymssqlserver.database.secure.windows.net`

Azure Resource health logs are telling me that the database does indeed go offline late at night or early in the morning every few days for about 5 to 10 minutes but these offline times do not overlap with the connectivity issues.

The error always occur on remote, TFS hosted build agents, never on a local one.

Autoclose is turned off.

Comment: Instead of "TFS hosted agents", do you mean ["VSTS hosted build agent"](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/hosted-pool)? This are the ones located on Azure, the Microsoft Cloud.

Comment: @LucaCappa Yes, I meant VSTS hosted build agent.

Comment: According  to the error info` A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.` Seems something block the connection. Could you ping successful between two servers? Did you double check the Firewall settings?

Comment: Database connection is fine most of the time. And so are firewall settings.  Looking at the aggregate for past few weeks I can see that only around 15% of builds failed. So, yes, around 85% success rate.The painful thing about it is that the dynamic of these failures varies. Sometimes I don't see them for a few days. Sometimes I get a few failed builds in a row. My internet connection is not involved in any way as this is M$ hosted agent talking to M$ hosted database which excluded lots of possible reasons for such failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that worked for me was to change the network protocol from the deafult, named pipes to TCP.
My connection string now looks like:

```
tcp:mymssqlserver.database.windows.net
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem should be related to the Firewall Settings of you SQL Database on Azure. 
I would suggest to:

- verify whether the *Azure SQL Database Deployment* task has the parameter "Specify Firewall Rule Using" set to "Auto-Detect"; this is a must when using Hosted Build Agent;
- enable verbose logging on the Build Definition (by setting System.Debug to True in the variable section), run the Build and verify whether the *Azure SQL Database Deployment* task is successfully setting the Firewall Rules;
- verify whether the on premise build agent machine is already enlisted as allowed client in the Firewall Settings of your SQL Database, this would be the reason the deployment always works on that 'local' build agent;
- read the Troubleshoot section at [SQL DB Firewall Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure) and spot any possible culprit of your setup.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Have checked your advises and none of them solved the problem. The biggest challenge with these failures is that they are intermittent. I get successful connections most of the time.

Comment: If you're seeing intermittent connection problems, are you seeing particularly high load on your database?